# Gradient of brightness in polygon in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Can I use opencv to draw a greyscale polygon, where the brightness of the each pixel is determined by interpolation from the vertices?

Code:

```
cv::fillConvexPoly(frame, &draw[0], (int) draw.size(), color);
```

Instead of `color` I would like to add an array of colors/brightnesses for each vertex, and then the final drawn polygon should have colors/brightnesses linearly interpolated from the vertex values.

Comment: How about adding some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can do this to edit a specific pixel:
`Vec3b pixel = image.at<Vec3b>( Point(x,y) );`
and `image.at<Vec3b>( Point(x,y) ) = pixel;`

Now just go and implement whatever drawing functionality you want.

(If you are having a specific issue, then please edit your question to clarify so I can then update this answer to be more specific. )

## Edit:

Thank you for specifying what it is that you are actually asking. Really this is not something that OpenCV is meant for. (It is a computer vision library, not a image manipulation library. ) Take a look at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/ as this will likely have what you need.

#RightToolForTheJob

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's doesn't quite answer what I tried to ask. I am very sorry for my not being precise. I have updated the question to better explain what I meant. But thanks again!

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is the right approach. Argh, more libraries to add :).

Comment: @Julius You are very welcome. Using Imagemagick and Opencv together isn't extremely common, but not unheard of. (I have done it a few times) You could go and write a bunch of code yourself if you really want to just use one library, but they are completely different in functionality and intent and you likely would be far better off just using both libraries. (That or depending on what you are doing, you can just remove OpenCV altogether because Imagemagick has all the functionality you require. )